# SQL order of execution

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I wonder how this query is executing successfully. As we know 'having' clause execute before the select one then here how alias name used in 'select' statement working in having condition and not giving any error.
[image: Running sql queries in Azure DataBricks]

Comment: I don't know about the internals, but it seems valid as per [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-having.html#:~:text=The%20HAVING%20clause%20is%20used,with%20a%20GROUP%20BY%20clause.)

Answer (score -1):

> As we know 'having' clause execute before the select one

This affirmation is wrong.  The `HAVING` clause is used to [apply filters in aggregation functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) (such as `SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN` and `MAX`).  Since they need to be calculated BEFORE applying any filter, in fact, the `SELECT` statement is done when the `HAVING` clause start to be processed.

---

Even if the previous paragraph was not true, it is important to consider that SQL statements are interpreted as a whole before any processing.  Due to this, it doesn't really matter the order of the instructions: the interpreter can link all references so they make sense in runtime.

So it would be perfectly feasible to put the `HAVING` clause before the `SELECT` or in any part of the instruction, because this is just a syntax decision.  Currently, `HAVING` clause is after `GROUP BY` clause because someone decided that this syntax makes more sense in SQL.

Finally, you should consider that allowing you to reference something by an alias is much more a *language feature* than a rational on how the instruction is processed.

Comment: Then what's the significance of order of execution in SQL?

So it would be perfectly feasible to put the HAVING clause before the SELECT or in any part of the instruction, because this is just a syntax decision. Currently, HAVING clause is after GROUP BY clause because someone decided that this syntax makes more sense in SQL.

Comment: @KumarSanu Can you reformulate your question? I wasn't able to understand, sorry...

Comment: @nbk mentioned the order of execution above where we can see "having" is in step 4 and "select" is in step 5. In our query we have defined alias in step 5. Then how that alias(defined in step 5) before executing step 5 is working in step 4?

Answer (score -1):

the order of exution is

1. Getting Data (From, Join)
2. Row Filter (Where)
3. Grouping (Group by)
4. Group Filter (Having)
5. Return Expressions (Select)
6. Order & Paging (Order by & Limit / Offset)

I still don't get, why you are asking about, syntactially your seelect qiery is correct, but if it the correct result we can not know

Comment: I want to ask how "having" clause working with alias used in "select" statement. According to you, "having" clause execute before "select" then how this alias is working in having clause.
I feel it should be  "having avg(Income)>100000" instead then it will follow order of execution.

Comment: After step 3 all values where calculated so the as aliases exist for having to be filtered , but not for step 2 there you filter the data from the from clause

Comment: So you mean alias defined in select statement can work with having clause defined in step 4 but not with where clause in step 2.  But this will violate the order of execution rule right as step 5 didn't execute yet but the defined alias(Avg_Income) there is working in step 4?

Comment: why will this violate anything, and yes where clause work with the columns from the tables which are defined in the from clause with all joins, the having clause works with the column names that are in the select independent if they have an alias or not.

Answer (score -1):

Spark SQL engine is obviously different than the normal SQL engine because it is a **distributed** SQL engine.  The normal SQL order of execution does not applied here because when you execute a query via Spark SQL, the engine converts it into optimized DAG before it is distributed across your worker nodes. The worker nodes then do map, shuffle, and reduce tasks before the result is aggregated and returned to the driver node. Read more about Spark DAG [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/dag-in-apache-spark/).

Therefore, there are more than just one selecting, filtering, aggregation happening before it returns any result. You can see it yourself by clicking on Spark job view on the Databricks query result panel and then select **Associated SQL Query**.

So, when it comes to Spark SQL, I recommend we refer to [Spark document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-having.html#examples) which clearly indicates that **Having clause can refer to aggregation function by its alias**.